# difference between deploying a WCF Data Service on IIS and running it on localhost

Tags: android, iis, localhost, wcf-data-services

I am following a tutorial (http://anindita9.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/consuming-sql-serversql-azure-data-in-windows-phone-7-1-android-through-odata-wcf-data-services-entity-frameworks/) which says that i have to deploy my .net WCF Data service over IIS and then consume it on Android. When deploying the webservice on IIS, i am having some problems. So i need to know can Android consume the webservice when the WCF Data service is running on localhost? so can i skip resolving issues with IIS deployment.?
thanks.

Comment: What are the problems you're having? Provided everything is set up correctly, Android should have no problem consuming the service. How are you connecting to it on the Android side? Also, is the service going to be on the same machine as IIS? You would have a port conflict :(.

Comment: I'm connecting using odata4jClientBundle.jar and using its function OdataConsumer.getEntities() in Android. Odata has been successfully exposed on the localhost. it is accessable in the webbrowser, but not on android using the method i mentioned above. and yeah, IIS and the service are on the same machine.

Comment: The WCF service can't use port 80 then. It will collide with IIS. When you run the service out of the debugger (I'm assuming that's what you're doing), it runs on some other port. Are you using Visual Studio? If so, and if your project was created as a web service (or web application), right clicking on the project gives you the option to publish it to IIS as long as IIS is on the same machine. For a remote deployment, right clicking in VS gives you the option to build a deployment package which can be imported into IIS (if IIS has the managment tools installed).

Comment: yeah , i'm using vs2010..but my point is that if my Webservice is running fine on localhost, why do i have to deploy it on IIS in order to consume it on android.? the Android Client gives a Force close error when the service is running on localhost. is it why i have to deploy it on IIS? (same machine).

Comment: A force close error? Okay, we need to take care of that one first. Can you get any more detail regarding what's wrong? Does it work okay when you run it through the Android emulator? Also, I mistakenly got the impression from an earlier comment that you're using a browser. Are you using a browser (perhaps to check things?) and an Android app or just an Android app. If it's just an Android app that just uses the web service, IIS should not be necessary at all then so you should be able to run it on the machine without deploying through IIS.

Comment: Seconding mj_'s comment's here - you'll have one fewer things to sort through if you just deal with the IIS issue. If it's accessible (assuming from IIS) via the Web browser, then you don't actually have an IIS issue, you have a connectivity-to-Android issue. Can you confirm that you're able to connect to the OData service from a Web browser and issue a few basic queries?

Comment: Yeah, i have been using the browser only to check if Odata has been exposed properly. the Android cient is the only thing that is consuming the webservice. Furthermore, I am using the Android Emulator for consuming the webservice. As Mark Stafford said, it really is the connectivity-to-Android issue. Because i am able to issue queries on the web browser from the OData Service just fine. The Force Close Error comes up when the OdataConsumer.getEntities() is executed. (I have checked it using Log.v(tag, msg);).